# Libgdx, Label doesn't show any text

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I hope this question is not too trivial, but i can not figure out why the label I have created won't show any text (the label is placed below the settings button):

edit: i am using version 1.9.3

```
Label currentSong = new Label("test", new Label.LabelStyle(Assets.instance.fonts.defaultSmall,
                Color.BLUE));
        table.add(currentSong);

        if (debugEnabled) layer.debug();
        return table;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code and it works. You might have problems with your font. Is the button texts a image or you are using this font?

One possible problem is that you **dispose your font somewhere** before using it. So it's all black and you cannot see it because you are using a black background.

Paste all your code here. At least the part you allocate/dispose the font and you create the table, the buttons and this screen...

Some code you should call:
`stage.addActor(table);` in the `show()` method.

```
stage.act(delta);
stage.draw();
```

In the `render()` method.

I know you probably called everything correctly, otherwise the table wouldn't apear. So check the font dispose. If you still needs help, we need the source...

Comment: The call is indeed correct, i keep forgetting that the font i am using (Colbert) apparently only supports uppercase letters x). I appreciate your answer, if you hadn't told me that it works on your side, I probably would not have found the mistake :)